# Compressing java.util.List[java.lang.Float] in Scala

Tags: java, scala, apache-flink

I am looking for a compression to **java.util.List** in scala which stores **java.lang.Float** but could not find any proper source which I can use to compress the List.

Application: I have around 100s of such lists in our streaming data and in order to reduce the memory storage requirement, I want to compress the lists. The code is written in Scala and is written for a Flink Streaming Job which generates a report which contain all the lists.

Comment: What do  you mean "compressing a list", you wouldn't gZIP a float?

Comment: You can compress the Float32 representation to Float16, even if you can afford losing some information you can transform to int8 representation, saving 75% of memory space. This is what deep learning frameworks use at inference time.

Comment: Just gzip it...

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok gZipping a float? I am not sure if that can be done. What I was thinking is to convert the list to string and then gzip the string. But unable to find the right process to do that.

Comment: @EmilianoMartinez rightly said. But changing the data type in our data will help in disk requirement? We store the data in Elasticsearch which intake the data as json. Now making data type change from float32 to float16 will make a difference in storage requirement in Elasticsearch or any NoSQL DB?

Comment: @Dima Can you please in guiding to the right way to gzip the data in Scala?

Comment: @LeviRamsey I am more concerned over disk requirement rather than memory-efficiency as of now because we store the data in a store(ElasticSearch) and we need to reduce the disk requirement.

Comment: If you're concerned with the storage consumption in Elasticsearch or another (non-toy) datastore, nothing you do on the Java side will optimize that.  Note that datastores which are oriented toward fast queries (which is a fair description of Elasticsearch) will in general be rather inefficient in their storage because the most effective ways to optimize query speed tend to involve consuming more disk.

Comment: @AlokSingh Check out [GzipOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html). But to echo the other comments, that likely doesn't matter, because Elasticsearch will likely compress the data it stores way more efficiently tjam you ever could.

Comment: @LeviRamsey How about storing the compressed data in the Elasticsearch? If we compress the data before even sending it to ElasticSearch, isn't it that it should save the disk space?

Comment: @Dima I agree that Elasticsearch will compress the data more efficiently. But how about compressing the data before hand only and giving compressed data to ElasticSearch and then ElasticSearch will try to compress this data again when storing in disk. Won't it help in reducing the disk requirement?

Comment: @AlokSingh aside from some specifically designed corner cases, double-compression typically results in a (slightly) _larger_ result (because of extra headers and dictionaries that need to be added) ... but you can try it and see for yourself how it works out in your case. One possible reason to compress on the client side I can think of is to reduce the network traffic, which may or may not be worth doing in your case.

Comment: I couldn't find any proper resource where I can see the implementation for the compression. 
What i have done now is that i have kept all the lists under a util.Map[String, java.util.List[java.lang.Float]] and thinking to compress this whole Map. 
Can you help on how I can achieve this?
@Dima

Comment: @AlokSingh did you check out the link I posted above? [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html) it is again.